# Constrained regression for binary dependent variable

Tags: survival, optimization, panel-data, glmm, weighted-mean

I would like to discuss the methodology for the following case: I have a data for several patients over several years for **5 factors** describing the health of a  particular patient. Every **factor consists of one or more questions** depending on its comprehensiveness and importance. **Each question is assigned to one of the four ordinal categories**, which indicates patient's health condition within the factor. The best category is 1, while the worst one is 4. 
My task is to **determine the final category using** some kind of **weighted average** and then **round the result** to be in {1, 2, 3, 4}, so it's basically some kind of a scorecard/unbalanced longitudinal data.

However, my **dependent variable**, which I want to calibrate these weights on, **is binary**, indicating whether the patient is alive or not in a way it is 0 when alive and 1 when deceased, thus when turning to 1, the following year the patient is no longer in the data . Patients can also be cured and then they disappear from data as well without having indicator variable equal to 1.

The problem is the **weights have to be non-negative and sum up to 1**, and there will be no intercept in the regression equation (weighted average). Another restriction is that **each of the 5 factors has to have weight of at least 10%**, so if the 1st factor consists of e.g. 4 questions, the sum of the associated 4 weights should be at least 0.1.

I was thinking about some **generalized linear models** (logit, probit, survival analysis) with applying the mentioned **linear constraints** into some optimization **quadratic programming** algorithm, but I find the concept rather complicated, I don't really know what would be the best model and how to program it in SAS or R. I would be very thankful if anyone can help with some similar example or idea.